# Visual studio extension for capturing keystrokes

Tags: visual-studio

I am interested in writing a visual studio extension that has hooks to allow me to capture keystrokes from the code editor and record them for use later. Visual studio extensions seem like a big topic so I am looking for some help getting started.

Is there a forum for visual studio extensions?

What type of extension should I create?

Are there any sample extensions that access keystrokes?

Answer (score 1):

See for example the [Text Macros](https://github.com/xps/VSTextMacros) extension that records characters that you type in the code editor.

Comment: I found [this info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885240.aspx) to be very useful too.

Comment: This [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751086/visual-studio-text-editor-extension) was also helpful